# What are the uses of if null in the programming of phone apps by flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, console

do we need to if null for small apps and big app and what is uses for flutter apps and console apps.
I asking this quotation what it is and how to use for performance

Answer (score 1):

Null isn't about performance.  The purpose of null is that sometimes you need to return a failure value-  for example, if you have a function that returns the author of a book, you can use a null return to show that you don't know who the author is.  The other options are to throw an exception (bad for performance reasons and readability of code if this is a normal case) or to return a special sentinel value (say always return 9999.  Which is obviously a problem is 9999 is a valid value the function may want to return).